# What happens when BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER fails in oracle

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, triggers

I have a small doubt regarding BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER in oracle,
my trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER some_trigger BEFORE INSERT
ON some_table   REFERENCING NEW AS newRow  
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
some_var          number(25, 4);

BEGIN
-- do some stuff
    :newRow.some_column  :=some_var;

 exception
      when no_data_found then
  NULL;
    when others then
    NULL;
END;
```

Here the update which I am doing on newRow.some_column is an optional thing, so my requirement is that even the trigger fails, the newRow should be inserted into the table and this is why I am eating up exceptions.

Is my assumption correct that if I eat up exception, the newRow will be inserted into the table in all scenarios ?

Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exception "handling" will make sure that the insert succeeds, even if you have an exception in your trigger.

Some thoughts:

1. Your current code cannot cause a `NO_DATA_FOUND`-exception.
2. Do you really want your code to fail silently?
3. Why do you catch both `NO_DATA_FOUND` and `OTHERS` and ignore both? `OTHERS` will catch `NO_DATA_FOUND` too.

**EDIT**

I'd just catch the `NO_DATA_FOUND` and add a **good** comment about why you can silently ignore it in your case.
Make sure that your SELECT only returns a single row, otherwise `TOO_MANY_ROWS` needs to be handled too.

Ignoring `OTHERS` is generally considered bad practice. Your code could fail and you'd never notice. There is a new [Compiler Warning](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/PlsqlNewFeaturesAndEnhancements_11gR1.php#new_plsql_compiler_warning) for this, actually.

Comment: Thanks peter, 1. the commented part "-- do some stuff" fires a select query which may cause a NO_DATA_FOUND. 2. Yes, I want to fail silently as this is an optional update. 3. I will catch and gobble only "OTHERS". thanks again.